# Should I vote to close a question asked by a confirmed and deleted sockpuppet account?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, sock-puppets

I've been flagging a user numerous times, first resulting in a `1 week` suspension, then a `1 month` suspension. For those of you who read my *(now deleted)* question *[What to do when you're fed up with flagging the same person?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269475/what-to-do-when-youre-fed-up-with-flagging-the-same-person)* knows who I'm referring to.

Yesterday I flagged the same user again resulting in a `1 year` suspension.

> **Should I vote to close a question asked by a confirmed and deleted sockpuppet account? 
> And if so, which close reason should I use?**

Some of the questions are answered by others, but there is one questions that is only answered (-2, accepted) by the offender. Is that worth keeping around?

Comment: Vote to close for the normal reasons; focus on the content, not the person there.

Comment: @MartijnPieters The I guess a close vote would be appropriate as the quality of both the question and  the answer is very very poor.

Comment: You downvote for quality, vote to close if it is off-topic. If the question and answer are downvoted the roomba will take care of deletion.

Comment: @MartijnPieters What's roomba?

Comment: The automated deletion script; [Turbocharging the Roomba: solutions for premature deletion](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/173513)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, in most circumstances you would treat the question as you would any other question asked by a legitimate user.

However, since the main purpose of illegitimate alt accounts is either to evade question bans, or to farm rep for the main account, the vast majority of questions they post won't be good or useful for the community because they're simply not going to waste any time writing questions of any redeeming quality. You'll find yourself downvoting or voting to close many of these. And that's OK.

One habit that some of these folks tend to take to is to steal existing questions and answers for themselves in the hopes of riding on their popularity and in order to seem legitimate. If you're in the loop, you'll spot these pretty easily. Just vote to close these questions as duplicates as you normally would, and, optionally, flag them for our attention so we can see if there's anything shady going on — because nobody in their right mind would copy a question word-for-word, let alone *its answer*.

Sometimes you might not find any issues with a question by a deleted user. There isn't much of a reason to downvote or vote to close it then. And that's OK too.